# Trying to filter based upon a value in another table

Tags: django

I have 2 tables as

```
class ItemFollowers(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Items, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='item')
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='user')
```

And the other one is

```
class UsrPosts(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey('Items', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='item')
    # Some other fields
```

How can I select the `UsrPosts` related to the `items` followed by some `user`? i.e. I can have records in `ItemFollowers` like (item0, user0), (item1, user0), (item5, user0). I need to filter `UsrPosts` based upon the user (aka. `request.user.id`)

Here is a inefficient non-working way to get `UsrPostts`

```
itms = ItemFollowers.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
qry = Q(item_id=itms[0].item.id) | ..... | Q(item_id=itms[N].item.id)
posts = UsrPosts.objects.filter(qry)
```

Is there some filter magic to get it in one transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
itms = ItemFollowers.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).values‌​_list('item')
posts = UsrPosts.objects.filter(item__in = itms)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! there is just slight error in the first line. It should be `ItemFollowers.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).values_list('item')`.
If there is no a better answer that makes it in one transaction, I will make this as the accepted answer. Thanks a million times!

Comment: Alright, using django_debug_toolbar, it looks like it actually takes one query to run these 2 lines. Thanks again!